# Testing MvvmCross/Monodroid App with Robotium

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, robotium

Does anyone has ever made it to test a Monodroid app with Robotium?
I'm struggling and I'm not sure if it is eve possible?

I tried to test the deployed apk on an emulator.

Are there any good alternatives to write UI-tests? I heard about Calabash...

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use Xamarin TestCloud? http://xamarin.com/test-cloud